# Angular Jasmine Unit Testing: Mocking the results of a HTTP Request that is called in a service called from a component

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

Hi folks: I am attempting to write some unit tests for a change to a component where we change the order in which objects are returned from a service. I'm really struggling with how to mock the http request. These tests are to be written in karma/jasmine for angular

plans-component.ts

```
// this method is called in the constructor 

  getPlans() {
    this.randomService.getRandomItems(this.id).subscribe(
      (data: RandomItem[]) => {
        this.activeItems = data.filter(e => e.isActive === true);
        this.randomItems = data.filter(e => e.isActive === false);
        this.loading = false;
      },
      (err: ResponseError) => { this.handleError(err); },
      () => { this.loading = false; }
    );
  }
```

Then we have this get request inside the file for randomService:

```
  /* GET */
  getRandomItems(id: string): Observable<RandomItem[] | ResponseError> {
    return this.get<any>(`/items/${id}/getRandomItems`).pipe(
      map(res => {
        const activeItems: RandomItem[] = res.activeItem as RandomItem[];
        const pendingItems: RandomItem[] = res.pendingItem as RandomItem[];
        return activeItems.concat(pendingItems);
      })
    );
  }
```

In my spec, I have created spys for the dependencies of the plans-component.ts constructor and have managed to instantiate the component. I've introduced a spy   randomSpy.getRandomItems.and.returnValue(of([]));

I want to test the results of this getPlans method as I test the component but I've no idea how to mock the results of the http request that it calls in the service. If anybody could share some resources on where to look for advice on what to do it would be great!

Thank you

Comment: Can somebody please help with this I am very lost

Answer (score 0):

Since you've introduced a spy `randomSpy.getRandomItems.and.returnValue(of([]));`, `getRandomItems` should return this.

Try something like this:

```
it('should have one activeItems and one randomItems', () => {
  // mock the response
  randomSpy.getRandomItems.and.returnValue(of([{ isActive: true }, { isActive: false }]));
  // call the method
  component.getPlans();
  // assert your expectations
  expect(component.activeItems.length).toBe(1);
  expect(component.randomItems.length).toBe(1);
});
```

[This](https://testing-angular.com/) is a good link in learning Angular unit testing.